# JDK 17 accessExternalSchema issue in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, xsd, java-17

In Eclipse RCP I have a plugin that has dependencies of a jar.
In this jar, inside a package called "xsd" there are some .xsd files.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npv0u.png)

In the same jar there is a class that internally, when instantiated, calls these .xsd files.

The problem I face is that at runtime with JAVA 17, when I call this class, Eclipse gives me the following exception:

`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: bundleresource://1142.fwk1919905302:2/xsd/message.xsd; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 100; schema_reference: Failed to read schema document 'service.xsd', because 'bundleresource' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.`

I tried to insert the property into the Eclipse launcher:
`-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all`
but I was not successful.

Comment: _"I tried to insert the property into the Eclipse launcher"_ - Please be more specific: Where exactly did you insert what and then which way did you choose to run it?

Comment: Could you share more of the exception ?
Like complete / formatted stacktrace (in \`\`\` enclosing tags)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, for me adding the jaxb-runtime dependency solved it

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```